# Mongoid ObjectID not escaped in JSON generated by to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

When using to_json on a Hash or Array which contains mongoid object IDs, the ID is not escaped in the JSON. I have to cast it as a string.
So that everytime I'm serialiazing hashes or arrays that contains ObjectIDs, the resulting JSON is malformed.

I'm using Mongoid 4 master with Rails 4.

```
[26] pry(main)> [Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new].to_json
=> "[51d2f368d0068664e0000002]"

[27] pry(main)> [Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new.to_s].to_json
=> "[\"51d2f425d0068664e0000003\"]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be resolved on the Master Branch

```
[Moped::BSON::ObjectId.new].to_json
=> "[{\"$oid\":\"51d2ff0322cf02e1a5000001\"}]"
```

ObjectId in MongoDB is more than a String. So it might be wise here to convert it to a string before that anyway.